# Text won't show

Tags: mysql

I have this query;

```
<?php

$oQuery = mysql_query("SELECT alertboxheader FROM cms_settings");
while($rQuery=mysql_real_escape_string($oQuery)){
echo $rQuery['alertboxheader'];   }
?>
```

But it doesn't show any texts!
I need to get this from the database;
http://i50.tinypic.com/30wva0x.png

[image]

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings Ray.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`? Try, `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
<?php

    $oQuery = mysql_query("SELECT alertboxheader FROM cms_settings");
    while($rQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($oQuery))
    {
        echo $rQuery['alertboxheader'];   
    }

?>
```

- [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

---

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that code doesn't work.
 
It gives me this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/pinkhotel/domains/pink-hotel.nl/public_html/content/tpl/styles/Habbo/system/header.php on line 170

 
Line 170 =     while($rQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($oQuery))

Comment: try running directly `SELECT alertboxheader FROM cms_settings` in ysql if it gives result.

Comment: It gives this error, #1054 - Unknown column 'alertboxheader' in 'field list' But on the picture that i gave, you can see it.

Comment: does table `cms_settings` contains `alertboxheader`?

Comment: are you sure you are selecting correct database?  do you have any dummy database that has almost the same as your current database?

Comment: what did you do with your query?

Comment: I've maded a new table, and used that one. But i have editted the query you gave me, and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `select value from cms_settings where variable='alertboxheader';` and don't forget what J W said.

Comment: grr didnt see the hidden comments. this was anwered an hour ago. Please accept then that was given then.